# Can i develop an app using Kinect with Metro UI on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, kinect

i have a question, can i develop an app using Kinect with Metro UI and it run on Windows 8 ?
Thank !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can . but not directly on Metro UI .

The Kinect libraries are not compatible with Windows Store apps and therefore you cannot add a reference to a legacy library that works against the Kinect SDK. But you can use **Web Socket protocol which supported by Metro Style App and .Net App.**

Check this out :

[wise team](http://wiseteamtn.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/kinect-your-metro-style-app/)

[InterKnowlogy Kiosk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nyLDaB-t4c)

[Project ISARA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYtZLCqMmxA)

[Teudu](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/A-Metro-inspired-Kinect-driven-visual-communication-system-Teudu)